# Importing Data from a Microsoft Access File on a Mac

Tags: macos, ms-access, jdbc

I have an MS-Access mdb file that I need to import data from into my mysql instance. I am on a mac, is there any free/OSS tools that allow me to do that? If not, is there a free/OSS JDBC driver that I can use to extract the data I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). Note that this doesn't support Access 97 databases, however, only 2000+.

For Access 97, the only thing I'm aware of is [mdbtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/), but that's a C library, so you'll have to write some JNI glue code if you want to use it from Java; also, it's not maintained anymore, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Jackcess supports Access 97 files for reading, but not for writing.

Answer (score 1):

[UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is a pure-Java JDBC driver that can read from and write to Access 2000 and newer databases. (Access 97 files are supported read-only.) It will work on any machine that runs Java.

For more details see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Answer (score 0):

Is your Access MDB on mac?

Does the mac Access have the option of using linked tables?
If so, you can create a Linked Table from Access MDB to mySQL. Then, you could treat mysql tables as if it were part of MS-Access.

EDIT: See if [this](http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?t=25426) helps.

Comment: I only have the mdb file, I don't have Microsoft Access Application. What I want is the other way round, importing from that file into my mysql database. I dont want to have to buy Microsoft Access to do that.

Comment: You don’t need to install ms-access on a win computer to pull data out. You can even use windows scripting to pull data out as text.

All recent versions of windows (even going back to win 2000) have the ability to pull data out of an mdb file without having to install ms-access. So no additional software need be installed on a windows box to pull out data from a mdb table.

Your problem here is not purchasing ms-access. Purchasing ms-access will not help you unless you have a place to install ms-access (which as I mentioned you don’t need anyway). Do you have boot camp?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a windows license and I don't want to buy one. Neither do I want to buy Office for Mac. Even if I run boot camp, I still need a windows license. My problem is solved however by Jackcess as suggested above, thanks everyone for the replies.

Comment: Access does not and has never run on Macs.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the MDB file using something like [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mdb-tool-for-microsoft-access/id513995545?ls=1&mt=12). This won't help you if you need to do it from within your app, but if you are ok exporting the data then using it, then this should help.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following way to convert;

1. Download ACCDB MDB Explorer
   http://accdb-mdb-explorer.en.softonic.com/mac
2. Open the MDB file
3. Export as SQL
4. Import in MySQL using MySQL Workbench.

Hope it helps..