# Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I want to manipulate a Microsoft Access database (.accdb or .mdb file) from my Java project. I don't want to use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge and the Access ODBC driver from Microsoft because:

- the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java SE 8 and is not supported (ref: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html)),
- the JDBC-ODBC Bridge does not work properly with the Access ODBC driver when text includes Unicode characters with code points above U+00FF (ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982205/2144390)), so such a setup would not be able to handle characters such as Greek, Russian, Chinese, Arabic, etc.,
- the Access ODBC driver from Microsoft only works in Windows, and
- there are separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Access Database Engine (and ODBC driver) which can be a nuisance for deployment.

I have seen other answers mentioning a JDBC driver for Access databases named [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). How can I set up my Java project to use this approach?

(Answers suggesting better ways of working with Access databases from Java would also be most welcome.)

Comment: Gord I would like to get in touch with you. Email address, is it possible? Cheers

Comment: You can use jdbc odbc classes from jre7 also in jre8 - see stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961

Answer (score 170, accepted):

[UCanAccess](https://github.com/spannm/ucanaccess) is a pure Java JDBC driver that allows us to read from and write to Access databases without using ODBC. It uses two other packages, [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), to perform these tasks. The following is a brief overview of how to get it set up.

### Option 1: Using Maven

If your project uses [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) you can simply include UCanAccess via the following coordinates:

**groupId:** net.sf.ucanaccess
**artifactId:** ucanaccess

The following is an excerpt from `pom.xml`, you may need to update the `<version>` to get the most recent release:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

### Option 2: Manually adding the JARs to your project

As mentioned above, UCanAccess requires Jackcess and HSQLDB. Jackcess in turn has its own [dependencies](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html). So to use UCanAccess you will need to include the following components:

[UCanAccess](https://github.com/spannm/ucanaccess) (ucanaccess-x.x.x.jar)
[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) (hsqldb.jar, version 2.2.5 or newer)
[Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) (jackcess-2.x.x.jar)
[commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) (commons-lang-2.6.jar, or newer **2.x version**)
[commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) (commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, or newer **1.x version**)

Fortunately, UCanAccess includes all of the required JAR files in its distribution file. When you unzip it you will see something like

```
ucanaccess-4.0.1.jar  
  /lib/
    commons-lang-2.6.jar  
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar  
    hsqldb.jar  
    jackcess-2.1.6.jar
```

All you need to do is add all **five (5)** JARs to your project.

> NOTE: Do **not** add `loader/ucanload.jar` to your build path if you are adding the other five (5) JAR files. The `UcanloadDriver` class is only used in special circumstances and requires a different setup. See the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34469789/2144390) for details.

**Eclipse:** Right-click the project in Package Explorer and choose `Build Path > Configure Build Path...`. Click the "Add External JARs..." button to add each of the five (5) JARs. When you are finished your Java Build Path should look something like this

[image: BuildPath.png]

**NetBeans:** Expand the tree view for your project, right-click the "Libraries" folder and choose "Add JAR/Folder...", then browse to the JAR file.

[image: nbAddJar.png]

After adding all five (5) JAR files the "Libraries" folder should look something like this:

[image: nbLibraries.png]

**IntelliJ IDEA:** Choose `File > Project Structure...` from the main menu. In the "Libraries" pane click the "Add" (`+`) button and add the five (5) JAR files. Once that is done the project should look something like this:

[image: IntelliJ.png]

### That's it!

Now "U Can Access" data in .accdb and .mdb files using code like this

```java
// assumes...
//     import java.sql.*;
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/__tmp/test/zzz.accdb");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT [LastName] FROM [Clients]");
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

### Disclosure

At the time of writing this Q&A I had no involvement in or affiliation with the UCanAccess project; I just used it. I later became a contributor to the project.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this library? Might be worth disclosing it if you do.

Comment: Can you use this to connect to an Excel Workbook (.xlsx) in Java 8?

Comment: @steinbitur No, you would need to use something like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) for that.

Comment: Hi Gord, do you want to give me some contact details?

Comment: @GordThompson How could I use it with Solr? For instance, I need the replacement of `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` in driver attribute of dataSource.

Comment: @sємsєм The driver class is `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`

Comment: @GordThompson That is a great answer. My entire class was stuck with this issue believing it to be a file system privilege error. Helped me loads and it took a surprising amount of digging to realize Oracle done away with the JDBC-ODBC bridge from Java 8.

Comment: Eclipse wanted a `try...catch` block around the java code to handle `SQLException`.  Otherwise, this works fine.  The only major inconvenience is that ucanaccess does not seem to have a maven repository.  This means we have to manually add the jars instead of just placing a dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: @CodeMed (1) The exception handling is omitted for clarity. Either a `try/catch` or  `throws` would be required, depending on the context. (2) Marco is planning to get UCanAccess hooked up with Maven, ref: [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/general/thread/3ab11fb4/). When that happens I'll update my answer.

Comment: @GordThompson, Have you tried UCanAccess on a Win10 Tech Preview system? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761407/how-to-write-to-an-access-database-on-windows-10

Comment: Why i'm getting this error? `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder`

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor - Please edit your [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32190312/2144390) to clearly explain the nature of your specific problem.

Comment: How about integrating UcanAcces datasource to JPA with Hibernate and Spring?

Comment: @GordThompson - Thanks, brilliant.  I happen to know you have an interest in Jython... I find this works in Eclipse with Jython but not from the CLI... please see my submitted "answer".  If you could shed some light it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How can I make that `accdb` file that contains oracle connection info? I think it's MS Access's file..

Comment: @Deckard - If you mean an .accdb file with ODBC linked tables that point to an Oracle database then UCanAccess won't be able to work with them. UCanAccess can manipulate linked tables that point to other .accdb or .mdb files, but it does not "do" ODBC. If you require further assistance please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Not only worked as through its response could set up a connection using the SQuirreL . Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer but could you draw more attention to lang 2.x and log 1.x. Maybe color it red and draw arrows pointing to it saying, "read carefully"? I just went through a 20 minute circle because I didn't pay close enough attention.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487474/how-do-a-i-resolve-a-java-jackcess-dependence-error

Comment: i wonder why the old jdbc is closed and removed but then people are still need of it?

Comment: @GordThompson, I am using this lib for my project to read .mdb file. Unfortunately, the file I am reading is very big i.e. 1.6 GB which takes a huge amount of time in prod(30 mins to get the connection-  `DriverManager.getConnection(url)`) and I need a certain portion of that file only.  Using ucanaccess v: 5.0.1 and jackcess version: 4.0.0. Any way around to reduce the time to load the file?

Comment: @user404 - http://ucanaccess.blogspot.com/2016/10/tip-loading-selected-tables.html

Comment: @GordThompson, thanks for the link. Anyway, my requirement is a bit different. I need to read all the tables but I need only a subset of the rows for each table. Any suggestion for that?